# What will be the value of $\det(A^2+B^2)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Let $A$ and $B$ be two $n\times n$ matrices such that $A \not=B, A^3 = B^3$ and $A^2 B = B^2 A$. Then what is the value of $\det \left( A^2 + B^2 \right)$?

Here I have done something.

$$A^3 = B^3 \implies(A-B)(A^2+B^2+AB)=0$$

Is my work right? Then how to do further? Well, I did mistakes here. But how can find the value of $\det(A^2+B^2)$?

Comment: Actually, just because $C\cdot D = 0$, you cannot say that $C=0$ or $D=0$. Therefore, your statement $A^2+B^2+AB=0$ is unproven.

Comment: No, $CD=0$ and $C\neq 0$ does not imply $D=0$ for matrices. $M_n(K)$ has zero divisors for $n>1$.

Comment: Also, are the matrices real or complex? If they are real, then they have the same determinant, for example.

Comment: I compute $(A-B)(A^2+AB+B^2)=A^3-BA^2+A^2B-BAB+AB^2-B^3\quad$ from which I cannot cancel terms at all. How does your first step work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the following observation may help:

set $X=A^2+B^2$

then
$$
XA=A^3+B^2A = B^3 + A^2B = XB
$$
so
$$
X(A-B) = 0
$$

Comment: So many up votes. Does the answer follow from this? I don't see it.

Comment: Either $\det X = 0$ or $\det(A-B) = 0$. In the latter case there is a vector $v \ne 0$ such that $Av = Bv$. Then what is $Xv$? And what does this imply about $\det X$?

Comment: @GitGud the observation was not intended as a complete answer. but, rightly or wrongly, it seemed sufficiently relevant to be worth noting

Comment: What will be the value of $det(A^2+B^2)$

Comment: Either det $X=0$ or $X$ is invertible and $A=B$

Answer (score 1):

@ my stak , to your question "is my work right ?", the answer is: no, it is catastrophic; in addition, you removed the most hilarious part of your work.

Since $A-B\not=0$, there is $u$ s.t. $v=(A-B)u\not=0$. According to the David's work, $Xv=0$ and $\det(X)=0$.